# Are the orbits of this discrete dynamical system bounded?

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Somehow I believe this should be true and easy to prove but cannot nail it down. A reference, proof, or counterexample will suffice. Didn't get any help [over at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025645/is-this-a-known-result-for-creating-a-family-of-collatz-like-functions) even with a bounty so I came here.

> **Assertion:** Let $f\colon \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ be a function.
> Assume that for some index set $I$, there are $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\Bbb Z$ such that
>
> - $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{i\in I}(a_i+b_i\Bbb N_0)$ and $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{i\in I}(c_i+d_i\Bbb N_0)$
> - For all $i\in I$, $n\in\Bbb N_0$, we have $f(a_i+b_in)=c_i+d_in$
> - For all $i\in I$, we have $a_ib_i\ge 0$ and $c_id_i\ge 0$
> - For all $i\in I$, if $b_i\ne d_i$, then $\frac{a_i-c_i}{b_i-d_i}>0$
> - For all $i\in I$, the set $\{\,f^{\circ k}(a_i)\mid k\in\Bbb N_0\,\}$ is finite
>
> Then for all $x\in \Bbb Z$, the set $\{\,f^{\circ k}(x)\mid k\in\Bbb N_0\,\}$ is finite.

The fourth bullet point is saying that if one element in a subdomain is greater than its corresponding element in the subrange, then all elements in that subdomain must be greater than their corresponding elements in the subrange. The same is true if one element in a subdomain is less than its corresponding element in the subrange.

$\color{black}{\text{Example 1}}$

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+1,  & \text{subdoman: 1, 3, 5, 7,...Subrange: 2, 4, 6, 8,...} \\
-x+2, & \text{subdoman: 2, 4, 6, 8,...Subrange: 0,-2,-4,-6...}\\
-x, & \text{subdoman: -1, -3, -5,...Subrange: 1, 3, 5, ...}\\
x+1, & \text{subdoman: -2, -4, -6,...Subrange: -1, -3, -5,...}\\
0, & \text{subdoman: 0 $\hspace{1.6cm}$ Subrange: 0}
\end{cases}$$
Note that the trajectories of the first elements $(1, 2, -1$ and $-2)$ of the subdomains all converge to $0$ implying that no trajectory will diverge.
For example, the trajectory of $6$ under $f$ is: $6\to-4 \to-3\to3\to4\to-2\to-1\to1\to2\to0.$

$\color{black}{\text{Example 2}}$

Here is a second example in which the first elements of the subdomains converge to the cycle $-1, 1$ and $0$ is excluded:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}x,  & \text{subdoman:2, 4, 6, 8,...Subrange: 3, 6, 9, 12...} \\
\frac{-3}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{subdoman:1, 3, 5, 7,...Subrange:-1,-4,-7, -10...}\\
\frac{-1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{subdoman:-1, -3, -5,...Subrange:1, 2, 3, ...}\\
\frac{1}{2}x, & \text{subdoman:-2, -4, -6,...Subrange:-1, -2, -3,...}
\end{cases}$$
In this example, the trajectory of 6 is $6\to9\to-13\to7\to-10\to-5\to3\to-4\to-2\to-1\to1.$

Comment: Why do you have $c_i, d_i \in \mathbb Q$?  If $c_i + d_i\mathbb N_0 \subseteq \mathbb Z$, then $c_i, c_i + d_i \in \mathbb Z$ and so $d_i \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: (Also, please don't abuse MathJax for formatting.  See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3928/is-it-ok-to-abuse-mathjax-for-emphasis .)

Comment: Question previously posted to m.se, currently has a bounty, no mention on either site of the post on the other. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025645/is-this-a-known-result-for-creating-a-family-of-collatz-like-functions

Comment: @LSpice Thanks. You are correct. I'll make that change.

Comment: You might get a better response is you used a title that's more descriptive.

Comment: @joesilverman Any suggestion?  "Seeking a counterexample or proof to the Boundedness of this family of Functions?

Comment: I changed the tags to something more appropriate. This is not about sequences in the sense of sequences-and-series, and I don't see any vector spaces. But people do study this type of thing in discrete-time dynamical systems.

Comment: @Math777 I think something like "Are the orbits of this discrete dynamical system bounded?"

Comment: David Robert's suggestion for a title is good.

Comment: "Didn't get any help over at MSE even with a bounty...." The bounty currently still has four days to run.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Any suggestion to the wording is welcome.

Comment: In your assertion, your condition $\frac {a_i - c_i} {b_i - d_i} > 0$ is the same as $(a_i - c_i)(b_i - d_i) > 0$, which is easier to read and understand. Didn't you rather mean something like $\frac {a_i - c_i} {b_i - d_i}  > 1$?

Comment: @HugoManet Given the condition, $\frac {a_i - c_i} {b_i - d_i} > 0$ and $(a_i - c_i)(b_i - d_i) > 0$ are saying the same thing, which is, if one element in a subdomain is greater than its corresponding element in the subrange, then all elements in that subdomain must be greater than their corresponding elements in the subrange. The same is true if one element in a subdomain is less than its corresponding element in the subrange.